# How to change the margins between the items in fisheye effect in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I saw this fish eye effect rendering js and tried to use it in a site HTML.It works fine but i am unable to change the space between the items. Does anybody know how to change the space between the items?
This is the Html/js code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $('#dock').Fisheye(
                {
                    maxWidth: 50,
                    items: 'a',
                    itemsText: 'span',
                    container: '.dock-container',
                    itemWidth: 75,
                    proximity: 90,
                    halign : 'center'
                }
            )
        }
    );

</script><div id="topbutton-container">
<div style="float:left; width:17px; margin:0px;"><img src="images/topbutton-left.jpg" /></div>
<div id="topbutton" align="center"><div class="dock" id="dock">
  <div class="dock-container">
  <a class="dock-item" href="index.html"><img src="images/home.png" alt="home" /><span>Home</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="projects.html"><img src="images/projects.png" alt="contact" /><span>Projects</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="course.html"><img src="images/course.png" alt="portfolio" /><span>Course</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="testimonial.html"><img src="images/music.png" alt="music" /><span>Testimonial</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="latest-updates.html"><img src="images/history.png" alt="history" /><span> Latest Updates</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="contact.html"><img src="images/contact.png" alt="calendar" /><span>Contact</span></a> 
</div>
</div></div>
<div style="float:left; width:17px; margin-top:0px;"><img src="images/tobutton-right.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.dock-item{margin: 0 30px;}`

Comment: @Dev Not working, only affecting the last div/anchor(i.e contacts)

Comment: Wish I can see that in fiddle.

Comment: can you create demo on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Dev Ok..I'll do it within two hours. Right now in office.

Answer (score 0):

do you included all the supporting files?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/interface.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/interface-fisheye.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: yes i did.Changing the margin values( and other style values of dock items) is only affecting the last div/anchor(i.e contacts).